# Looping Through XML Inner Node using SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<RentListings>
    -<RentListing>
        <Country>UAE</Country>
        <State>Dubai</State>
        <City>Dubai</City>
        <District>Dubailand District</District>
        <Comm>Arabian Ranches</Comm>
        <SubComm>Al Mahra</SubComm>
        <Bedroom>2</Bedroom>
        -<Images>
            <ImageUrl>http://cdn.example.com/img/1.jpg</ImageUrl>
            <ImageUrl>http://cdn.example.com/img/2.jpg</ImageUrl>
            <ImageUrl>http://cdn.example.com/img/3.jpg</ImageUrl>
        </Images>
        <Last_Updated>Jun 1 2014 9:46AM</Last_Updated>
        <Unit_Status>Vacant</Unit_Status>
    </RentListing>
</RentListings>
```

Here is my Code to extract the details from the XML

```
$XMLrent = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_here);
foreach($XMLrent->RentListing AS $oEntry){
    echo $oEntry->City;
    **[Images should be place here]**
}
```

My Problem is I dont know how to retrieve and loop through the `<Images>` nodes

Comment: Problem Solved  foreach ($oEntry->Images->ImageUrl AS $ImageUrl) { echo $ImageUrl; }

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($oEntry->Images->ImageUrl AS $oImageUrl){
     echo $oImageUrl;
 }
```

Comment: it didn't work for me

This One works

    foreach ($oEntry->Images->ImageUrl AS $ImageUrl) {
     echo $ImageUrl;
    }

Comment: A little explanation of the fact that ``SimpleXMLElement`` has a fluid interface that allows sub-element traversal easily would have been nice.